# displaying highchart in button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

i have a problem regarding this highcharts. I am using Laravel as my framework. My problem is this: I have a button that has an on click event to get my data and plot it in highcharts. Now my first problem is this: When i click the button, the chart will appear and my data won't show, when i press the button again, then my data shows. Precisely my problem is this: I need to double click the button to show my data from highcharts and whenever i will hit it in three clicks, then my data in highchart will duplicate.

Here is my code:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger form-control" onclick="aw();"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart" ></i> View</button>
```

Javascript code:

```
function aw(){

     strat = $('#reservationtime').data('daterangepicker').startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
     dend  = $('#reservationtime').data('daterangepicker').endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
     sec = $('#repsec').val();

     diff(strat,dend);    
}

function diff(from, to) {

    var datFrom = new Date(from);
    var datTo = new Date(to);
    var fromYear =  datFrom.getFullYear();
    var toYear =  datTo.getFullYear();
    var diffYear = (12 * (toYear - fromYear)) + datTo.getMonth();

    for (var i = datFrom.getMonth(); i <= diffYear; i++) {
        arr.push(monthNames[i%12] + " " + Math.floor(fromYear+(i/12)));
        $.ajax({         
        url: "{{ url('user/get-report') }}/" +sec+"/"+strat+"/"+dend+"/"+monthNames[i%12]+"/"+Math.floor(fromYear+(i/12)),        
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",        
        success: function(data) { 

            if (data[0]['data'].length>0){
              for(i=0; i<data[0]['data'].length; i++){   
                datas.push(data[0]['data'][0].count);
              }
            }
            else{
              datas.push(0);
            }

            if (data[1]['data2'].length>0){
              for(i=0; i<data[1]['data2'].length; i++){   
                datas2.push(data[1]['data2'][0].count);
              }
            }
            else{
              datas2.push(0);
            }

            if (data[2]['data3'].length>0){
              for(i=0; i<data[2]['data3'].length; i++){   
                datas3.push(data[2]['data3'][0].count);
              }
            }
            else{
              datas3.push(0);
            }
        }   
      });
    }  

    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Attendance Report'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories:arr,
            crosshair: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'No of students'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y} student(s)</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Present',
            data:datas

            }
            , {
                name: 'Absent',
                data: datas2

            }, {
                name: 'Late',
                data: datas3
            }
        ]
    });    

    $('#report').show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are rendering the chart before your Ajax call completes. Calling the chart function after your ajax calls are completed should fix the problem.

It also appears that you have multiple AJAX calls fired in the `for-loop` so you will have to wait for all of them to finish before you can render the chart.

```js
function aw() {

  strat = $('#reservationtime').data('daterangepicker').startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  dend = $('#reservationtime').data('daterangepicker').endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  sec = $('#repsec').val();

  diff(strat, dend);
}


function diff(from, to) {

  var datFrom = new Date(from);
  var datTo = new Date(to);
  var fromYear = datFrom.getFullYear();
  var toYear = datTo.getFullYear();
  var diffYear = (12 * (toYear - fromYear)) + datTo.getMonth();
  // Keep a count of the number of expected Ajax Calls
  var count = diffYear - datFrom.getMonth();


  function renderIfReady() {
    if (--count > 0) {
      // There are still pending AJAX calls, return early
      return;
    }
    // All calls complete. Render Chart
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
      chart: {
        type: 'column'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Monthly Attendance Report'
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: ''
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: arr,
        crosshair: true
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
          text: 'No of students'
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
          '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y} student(s)</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
      },
      plotOptions: {
        column: {
          pointPadding: 0.2,
          borderWidth: 0
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Present',
        data: datas

      }, {
        name: 'Absent',
        data: datas2

      }, {
        name: 'Late',
        data: datas3
      }]
    });
  }
  for (var i = datFrom.getMonth(); i <= diffYear; i++) {
    arr.push(monthNames[i % 12] + " " + Math.floor(fromYear + (i / 12)));
    $.ajax({
      url: "{{ url('user/get-report') }}/" + sec + "/" + strat + "/" + dend + "/" + monthNames[i % 12] + "/" + Math.floor(fromYear + (i / 12)),
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(data) {

        if (data[0]['data'].length > 0) {
          for (i = 0; i < data[0]['data'].length; i++) {
            datas.push(data[0]['data'][0].count);
          }
        } else {
          datas.push(0);
        }

        if (data[1]['data2'].length > 0) {
          for (i = 0; i < data[1]['data2'].length; i++) {
            datas2.push(data[1]['data2'][0].count);
          }
        } else {
          datas2.push(0);
        }

        if (data[2]['data3'].length > 0) {
          for (i = 0; i < data[2]['data3'].length; i++) {
            datas3.push(data[2]['data3'][0].count);
          }
        } else {
          datas3.push(0);
        }

        renderIfReady();
      }
    });
  }



  $('#report').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click on view button you are pushing data to arrays like datas,datas2 and datas3.

solution for this is to make array empty whenever you click on function

```
  function diff(from, to) {
    var datas=[];
    var datas2=[];
    var datas3=[]
    //Your code here
    }
```